# Как принудительно скрыть класс во сплывающем окне с отображением стороннего сайта?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, modal

Как принудительно скрыть класс во сплывающем окне с отображением стороннего сайта?
Модуль всплывающего окна вызывает это самое окно через .
Необходимо скрыть класс .sidebar, при указании в css команды display: none; ничего не происходит, в консоли разработчика она отсутствует.
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно стиль этого элемента имеет больший приоритет. Попробуйте добавить !important.

```
display: none !important;
```

Если не поможет, то можно попробовать следующее:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

или так:

```
height: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
```